# Compile Smart Contract with Solidity on Windows 10

Tags: solidity, windows, compilation

I wanted to use solidity within geth in Windows 10. I tried the compiled version that comes with Ethereum 1.0 but it has an issue mentioned in this [thread](https://forum.ethereum.org/discussion/3837/compiler-error-in-greeter-windows).
I'd like to get a new binary of a newer version with this issue fixed. As I didn't find it, I'm trying to compile it by myself but I found the following errors:

If I compile it standalone, just downloading the package from here I get:

> 'Unknown CMake command "eth_policy"'.

If I try to compile solc (v 0.1.6) included in Ethereum 1.0 I get:

> 'Cannot open include file: 'pthread.h': No such file or directory [C:\Users\pablo\Desktop\solc-build\webthree-umbrella\solidity\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_24f2f.vcxproj]'

Any ideas?

Comment: Not answering directly your issue, but have you tried the online solidity compiler, visual studio code or visual studio?

Comment: Also you could try npm install solc

Comment: I've tried Visual Studio extension and I'm not able to make it work: http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/4022/unable-to-use-solidity-visual-studio-extension