# Unable to use Solidity Visual Studio Extension

Tags: solidity, dapp-development, visual-studio

I've installed Solidity Extension in Visual Studio and then created a new project. All looked fine except that the sample files have a + on the left which indicates with a tooltip 'pending add':
[image: Solidity example with pending add]

In addition to this, when I right click on any item of the project, the focus of the window changes to the README.html file contained in the project and the context menu hides immediately.

Am I loosing something or it isn't working?

Answer (score 1):

Probably something with the Visual Studio version you have.

I just installed it today and have no problems.

I did this:

- Went to the official Solidity extension page for VS: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/96221853-33c4-4531-bdd5-d2ea5acc4799
- From there, clicked on "Get Started for Free" on the top right corner:
  https://www.visualstudio.com/products/free-developer-offers-vs.aspx?slcid=0x409
- Downloaded "Visual Studio Community", it will install Visual Studio 2015
- After that, I installed solidity from the extension page
- Restarted PC

And all works fine, I don't see those +.

Comment: I'm using VS 2015.

Comment: Do you have TFS installed? Those + seem from TFS

Comment: No TFS installed